# Reliably select from a database table at fixed time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly 'active' CDR table I want to select records from it every say 5 minutes for those last 5 minutes. The problem is it has a SHA IDs generated on a few of the other columns so all I have to lean on is a timestamp field by which I filter by date to select the time window of records I want.

The next problem is that obviously I cannot guarantee my script will run on the second precisely every time, or that the wall clocks of the server will be correct (which doesn't matter) and most importantly there almost certainly will be more than one record per second say 3 rows '2013-08-08 14:57:05' and before the second expired one more might be inserted.

By the time for '2013-08-08 14:57:05' and get records `BETWEEN '2013-08-08 14:57:05'  AND '2013-08-08 15:02:05'` there will be more records for '2013-08-08 14:57:05' which I would have missed.

Essentially:

- imprecise wall clock time
- no sequential IDs
- multiple records per second
- query execution time
- unreliable frequency of running the query

Are all preventing me from getting a valid set of rows in a specified rolling time window. Any suggestions for how I can go around these?

Answer (score 0):

I probably not got all the details but to answer to your question title *"Reliably select from a database table at fixed time intervals"*...

I don't think you could even hope for a query to be run at "second precise" time.

One key problem with that approach is that you will have to deal with concurrent access and lock. You might be able to *send* the query at fixed time maybe, but your query might be *waiting* on the DB server for several seconds (or being executed seeing fairly outdated snapshot of the db). Especially in your case since the table is apparently "busy".

---

As a *suggestion*, if I were you, I would spend some time to think about queue messaging systems (like http://www.rabbitmq.com/ just to cite one, not presaging it is somehow "your" solution). Anyway those kind of tools are probably more suited to your needs.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm not really looking for that, I try not to have anything to do with relying on 'time', hence looking for cleverer programatic solutions

Comment: @Recc This is the title of your question *"Reliably select from a database table at fixed time intervals"* ;) Anyway, I edited my answer to point you to the first alternative solution that came to my mind

Comment: Should've been "Reliably select records within a set time window" perhaps, yes.. I dont really care about the frequency of the rolling window but they are intertwined as the window will be as long as the frequency still.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same clock then i see no reason why things would be wrong.  a resolution you would want to consider is a datetime table.   So that way, every time you updated the start and stop times based on the server time.... then as things are added it would be guarenteed to be within that timeframe.

I mean, you COULD do it by hardcoding, but my way would sort of forcibly store a start and stop point in the database to use.

I would use Cron to handle the intervals and timing somewhat.  Not use the time from that, but just to not lock up the database by checking all the time.

Comment: Not the same clock though, one machine is the db server another will be executing the script(query), but yes with cron, and exactly what I meant with unreliable frequency as cron might run it at any number of seconds after the minute hits :) and agreed, i cant rely on that

Comment: i would create a table for dates.  It seems kinda weird... but that way, you could ping it every 5 minutes.... scrape data in range.  Update the time table:  start = end.   end = end + 5min